# Pass form value in Laravel to Blade template

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm trying to find a way to pass a value entered in a Laravel form to the action page and can't find the right syntax.

Here's an excerpt of my Blade form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'thanks')) }}
 {{ Form::label('email', 'Email Address') }}
 {{ Form::text('email') }}
 {{ Form::submit('Sign Up') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

And here's my route:

```
Route::post('thanks',function($email)
{
$theEmail = $email;       
return View::make('thanks', $theEmail);
});
```

How do I correct the route so I can use `$theEmail` in my `thanks.blade.php` page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the variable from the posted form via `Input::get()`

```
Route::post('thanks',function()
{
   $theEmail = Input::get('email');
   return View::make('thanks')->with('theEmail', $theEmail);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm getting this error when I implement the change: "[2014-05-28 16:13:07] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array' in /Users/jlowery/testapp/bootstrap/compiled.php:8909"
Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::post('thanks',function()
{
   $data = [];
   $data['theEmail'] = Input::get('email');
   return View::make('thanks', $data);
});
```

And then in your blade file

```
{{ $theEmail }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Route::post('thanks',function()

{

```
 $email=Input::get('email'); 


return View::make('thanks')->with('email',$email);


});
```